# Convert a string array to csv file

Tags: csv, numpy, python-3.6

I am wondering how to use numpy convert the arrays below to a csv file

```
`[array(['1.5',' "school"','100'], dtype='<U8')
 array(['10.0',' -90',' "flower"'], dtype='<U11')]`
```

which looks like in this format.(with '' deleted)

```
`1.5, "school", 100
10.0, -90, "flower"`
```

Which methods should I use to get this?thx.

Comment: Can you post an example of what you've tried so far?

Comment: Loop through the list and write `"%s, %s, %s"%tuple(row)` to a file.